# Rails 5 - Circle CI - Heroku - Run migrations after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, circleci

After deploying to Heroku, I want the migrations to run after deployment. Tried following configuration in circle.yml -

```
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: <branch_name>
    heroku:
      appname: <appname
    commands:
      - heroku run rake db:migrate --app alldaydr:
        timeout: 400
      - bundle exec rake swagger:docs
    commands:
      - git push git@heroku.com:<appname> $CIRCLE_SHA1:master
      - heroku run rake db:migrate --app <appname>
```

It deploys successfully but doesn't run migrations. Any help/idea?

Comment: "deploys successfully" means other expected changes are available on heroku right?

Comment: Yes. The app is deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my configuration that works below. I have just one `commands` instruction and run rake migration just after push to Heroku. You can also get a hint of what's happening from the deploy logs on CircleCI.

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: <branch-name>
    commands:
      - "[[ ! -s \"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/shallow\" ]] || git fetch --unshallow"
      - git push git@heroku.com:<appname> $CIRCLE_SHA1:refs/heads/master
      - heroku run rake db:migrate --app <appname>:
          timeout: 400 # if your deploys take a long time
      - heroku run rake swagger:docs --app <appname>
```

Refer to [CircleCI's documentation](https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/continuous-deployment-with-heroku/) for more